# Member log in issue

Tags: java, authentication, system, bluej

I'm having an issue implementing a member log in, in to my library system. This is the code I have so for
Here is my code for from the main system.

```
    case 1:
    String StudentUser;
    System.out.println("\nEnter Student ID: ");
    StudentUser = br.readLine();
    for (StudentSignUp: memberList)
            {
              if (StudentSignUp.getStudentId().equals()){ 
                    newMember();
                    break;
                }else
                {
                    system.exit(0);
                }
            }
```

Here is the code for the member class...

```
public class Member
{
 private List<StudentSignUp> memberList;


public Member()
{
    memberList = new ArrayList<StudentSignUp>();  
}
public void newMember(StudentSignUp student)
{
    memberList.add(student);
}
public String toString()
{
    String totalmem = "\n ";
    for (int i=0; i<memberList.size(); i++)
    {
        StudentSignUp b = memberList.get(i);
        totalmem = totalmem + b.toString();
    }

    return totalmem;
}
```

}

Here is my code for the StudentSignUp Class...

```
public class StudentSignUp implements Serializable
{
// instance variables - replace the example below with your own
private int libraryNumber;
private String StudentID;
private String Username;
private String FullName;
private String Address;
private String email;
private String PhoneNumber;
/**
 * Add the required feilds to become a member.
 */
public StudentSignUp( int libraryNumber,String FullName, String
 StudentID, String Username, String Address, String email, String 
 strong textPhoneNumber)
{
    this.FullName = FullName;

    this.StudentID = StudentID;

    this.libraryNumber = libraryNumber;

    this.Username = Username;

    this.Address = Address;

    this.email = email;

    this.PhoneNumber = PhoneNumber;
}

public String toString()
{
    return "\nFullName: " +FullName + "\nStudentID: " +StudentID + 
    "\nLibrary Number: " +libraryNumber + "\nUsername: " +Username +  
 "\nAddresss:
 " +Address + "\nE-mail: " +email + "\nPhone Number: " +PhoneNumber;

}

public String getStudentId()
{
    return StudentID;
}
```

}

Comment: And what is the issue?

Comment: I cant get the log in to work.

Comment: @JohnMackinnon What kind of logging are you referring to? Your code is incomplete; try to provide the shortest piece of code that actually compiles, runs; then point out which part of that isnt working as you expected. Side question: what is `StudentSignUp.getStudentId().equals()` supposed to do?

Comment: First you need to change that StudentSignUp.getStudentId().equals(), that can be either null or blank - "", it will always create new blank arraylist, you havent used parameterised constructor in this code.

Comment: The code won't even compile, there are so many syntax errors in it, it's hard to decide where to start at all, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Public void newMember(StudentSignUp student)
{
    memberList.add(studend)
}
```